# Can I emulate hs-hide-initial-comment-block in vim?

Tags: vim, emacs, gvim

In emacs, there's a helpful command called `hs-hide-initial-comment-block` that will fold a comment block if it is the very first thing in a file.  This way, I can get straight to the code without having to worry about the licensing comment.  Is there any way to do this in vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to be handled by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250011